# does a tool like air bag opener exist for paper bag application?

Tags: equipment

There are these air bag openers that exists which are used in the food industry and assist with packing food: https://www.pack-secure.com/Bag-Opener-_c_513.html

Is there a tool, hand held or otherwise, that can be used for paper bags of this nature? [image]

The current option for opening bags like this is by shaking it up and down such that the air opens it. When doing over 100 of this it is not really practical. Note that the bag comes flat when buying in bulk.

Feel free to suggest if there is another appropriate SE for this question.

Comment: I've seen sandwich shops doing that and it is reasonably practical as far as I can tell. But shaking it seems a bad idea because you can easily break the bag. Why not put your hand in the bag then open your fingers?

Comment: that's not practical if there are over a thousand bags to open in a day. not ergonomically feasible either

Comment: I think this is on topic here, but you may want to post to lifehacks as well. I think they may have some good suggestions.

Comment: The trick is for when you have them stacked put kunckles on them and slowly, but firmrly turn it in cirlces. It will not also open the bags but also fan them out.

Comment: @SZCZERZOKŁY sorry could you clarify what you mean by knuckles Google doesn't return results

Comment: @Mel The ones on hand :). Put your fist on stack on paper and gently make circles with your wrist. Wow, looking for some clue I've even found a video on how to do that https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_cQfPaxn4Cw

Comment: @Johanna cross-posting is not ok on the SE network. If a question fits multiple sites, it’s the OP’s choice where to post it. And Lifehacks wouldn’t be happy if the question was explicitly about a tool that was designed for the purpose. I did post a link to this question on the Lifehacks chat.